# Read a JSON file vb.net Newtonsoft

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to read a simple JSON file using VB.NET and I really can't find an answer because whatever I try I get an error.  I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.  I'm not sure if I need to parse it as a json array using Dim jsonArray As JArray = JArray.Parse(json) or as an object.  I want to loop the object and write each of the elements to the variable so I can save them to a database.  I've done this in javascript but the vb is throwing me.

```
[  
   {  
      "Organization":"a",
      "Ref_ID":"33",
      "First":"Bob",
      "MI":"V",
      "Last":"Smith",
      "Suffix":""
   },
   {  
      "Organization":"a",
      "Ref_ID":"12",
      "First":"Mary",
      "MI":"",
      "Last":"Jones",
      "Suffix":""
   },
   {  
      "Organization":"Stony Brook",
      "Ref_ID":"74",
      "First":"Jonas",
      "MI":"S",
      "Last":"Green",
      "Suffix":""
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert the JSON into a list of (class) objects using Newtonsoft. The example below uses a form with a single textbox and button.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Const JSON As String = "[^   {^      'Organization':'a',^      'Ref_ID':'33',^      'First':'Bob',^      'MI':'V',^      'Last':'Smith',^      'Suffix':''^   },^   {^      'Organization':'a',^      'Ref_ID':'12',^      'First':'Mary',^      'MI':'',^      'Last':'Jones',^      'Suffix':''^   },^   {^      'Organization':'Stony Brook',^      'Ref_ID':'74',^      'First':'Jonas',^      'MI':'S',^      'Last':'Green',^      'Suffix':''^   }^]"
        txtJson.Text = JSON.Replace("^", vbCrLf).Replace("'", """")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click
        Try
            Dim xReturn As List(Of RandomPerson) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of RandomPerson))(txtJson.Text)

            Dim sMessage As String = ""

            For Each OnePerson As RandomPerson In xReturn
                sMessage &= OnePerson.Ref_ID & " // " & OnePerson.First & " // " & OnePerson.Last & vbCrLf
            Next OnePerson

            MessageBox.Show(Me, sMessage, "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch Exp As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, Exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class

'The class below was created by converting the example JSON into a C# class using: http://json2csharp.com/
'You can then convert the C# class into a VB.NET class by hand, or by using a tool like: http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

Public Class RandomPerson
    Public Property Organization As String = ""
    Public Property Ref_ID As String = ""
    Public Property First As String = ""
    Public Property MI As String = ""
    Public Property Last As String = ""
    Public Property Suffix As String = ""
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume js variable contain your json string then something like this:

```
Dim reader As New JsonTextReader(New StringReader(js))
    While reader.Read
        If reader.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If reader.Path.Contains("Ref_ID") Then
                Console.WriteLine("Ref_ID::" + reader.Value)
            End If
        End If
    End While
```

Remeber that reader goes through each key and value, for example in first read reader.Path would be "[0]Organization" and reader.Value would be "Organization". Secound read reader.Path would be "[0]Organization" and reader.Value would be it's value "a".
[0] means record number and when reader.Path="[1].Ref_ID" then your value will be 12

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do it like :

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization ' for reading of JSON (+add the reference to System.Web.Extensions library)
Dim JSONItems = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSOn_string)
```

Similar to what I answered in a different question
[Comparing files not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157471/comparing-files-not-working-as-intended/51159296#51159296)

Answer (score -1):

**Try something like this**

```
Dim json As String = rawresp
Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
Dim jsonArray As JArray = jsonObject("result")

For Each item As JObject In jsonArray
    textboxLast.Text = item.SelectToken("Last").ToString
Next
```

Comment: Your code will not work as written-- the JSON is an array, not an object, and it does not contain a property called "result" anywhere.