# add data to a datatable from JSON string - vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, datatable

I need to know how to populate `datatable` from `JSON` string in `vb.net` code.

**the JSON string**

`{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"Paper1:null,"StateId":"57ee","School":"1A","Received":"2018-07-03T08:10:05.22","TimeS":"00","STAT":"98","ScoreCard":"76"},{"Paper1:null,"StateId":"52ef","School":"1A","Received":"2018-07-03T08:10:05.22","TimeS":"00","STAT":"88","ScoreCard":"57"}]}`

I need to know how to populate above string to a `datatable`

The above string is in a `WebResponse`. So is there any way to read the `webresponse` (here I have used a `streamreader`, or any other good method) and populate to a datatable?

**my code which I got above string.**

```
        Dim rqst As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri_variable)
        Dim res_p As WebResponse
        rqst.Method = "GET"
        rqst.Headers.Add("apisign:" & sign) 
        res_p = rqst.GetResponse() 
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(res_p.GetResponseStream())
        Dim JSON_String as string = reader
```

**P.S: EDIT:** I included a screenshot for the user "CruleD"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYbP0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, this again.

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization ' for reading of JSON (+add the reference to System.Web.Extensions library)
Dim JSONC = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON_String)
```

Inspect JSONC with breakpoint. You will see how it looks then you decide what you want to do with it.

[Comparing files not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157471/comparing-files-not-working-as-intended/51159296#51159296)
Similar answer I gave in another thread.

Edit:

```
JSONC("result")(0)("Quantity")
```

First you get the contents of "result", then you select which collection you want, in this case first (so 0) then you search for whatever key you want again eg "Quantity" like you did for result originally.

There are other ways to do the same thing, but this one should be pretty straight forward.
There are 3 types of deserialization, check them out if you want.

Comment: thank you very much, at a break point it does contain all the details separately as an array it seems. But, how to access those information one by one? I tried `TextBox1.Text = JSONC(2)("result")("Object")(4)` but it throws an error `The given key was not present in the dictionary` .. and I included a screenshot of the arrays of JSONC. Please see the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Should be JSONC("result")(0)("Quantity") for example.

Comment: Thank you very much CruleD, it works .. I'll make this as an accepted answer.